# Can pact replace freemarker

Tags: pact

We interact with a lot of services in our api and use freemaker templates to mock the responses of the different services. Would using PACT(Consumer driven contract testing) be more beneficial for us in any way?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, Pact can be used as a replacement for [local stubs](https://docs.pact.io/getting-started/local-api-stubs).

If you need lots of flexibility in the responses, then it's probably going to be somewhat limiting.